# Maven assembly plugin fails with NullPointerException?

Tags: java, maven-2, build, nullpointerexception

I get a NullPointerException and I don't like it. It is a larger build with several submodules (which differ in their maven config only slightly), for most of the modules it does work, but for some not. Any ideas what the problem might be?

```
[INFO] [assembly:assembly]
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: src/assemble/all.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] null
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.maven.artifact.DefaultArtifact.equals(DefaultArtifact.java:358)
at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:376)
at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:200)
at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.artifact.DefaultDependencyResolver.buildManagedVersionMap(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:160)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.DefaultAssemblyArchiver.createArchive(DefaultAssemblyArchiver.java:179)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.mojos.AbstractAssemblyMojo.execute(AbstractAssemblyMojo.java:370)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:483)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:678)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:553)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:523)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:371)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:268)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:181)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:356)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:137)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:356)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 41 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jun 19 10:44:03 CEST 2009
[INFO] Final Memory: 32M/99M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: +1 for "and I don't like it"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at line 358 of the head revision, my guess is that something, somewhere has no version defined.

I don't really "know" Maven, but I'd suggest checking your versions carefully. Of course, it's possible that I'm not looking at the same source code as you're using - have a look at the source for your actual version to see what's at DefaultArtifact.java line 358.

Comment: Your idea brought me on the right track. Indeed I didn't specify a version in the dependency itself, because I moved all version declarations to the dependency management block in the *parent project* and the version apparently doesn't get resolved because it is declared as a range, and not a concrete version. I would consider that as a bug.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem. Turns out that my pom file had the version set to an application.property that wasn't defined.

Answer (score 1):

If the versions are not empty like Jon-skeet suggested it could be a maven-enforcer-plugin bug:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MENFORCER-156

Essentially, the maven-enforcer-plugin (in at least version 1.3) "puts the `MavenProject` in a state where it claims that all dependencies are resolved, but the artifact-files are not bound."

For me this reoccurred in version 1.4.1.